Disconnect from Google Colab progamatically
How do I disconnect from Google Colab programmatically using python? I want to be able to run a script then disconnect right after it finishes to save my allocated GPU time.

@IgnatiusReilly That is exactly what I want. Thanks. I have actually searched but what I got were the posts regarding "not" disconnecting from the Google Colab. Much appreciated.
